# Easy way to get a File Picker on Linux

Tags: c, linux, file, picker

I'm trying to write a small programme that needs to load a few files chosen by the user. I thought it'd be easier to use the Linux system's default file picker rather than write my own, but I literally don't have a clue where to even start looking.

So, can anyone recommend a quick and easy way to use the system's file picker on Linux in C?

Comment: There is no "system file picker" on Linux. It depends on the specific UI toolkit your program uses.

Comment: And many Linux systems (notably servers, e.g. any VPS you can rent for a few $ or €) don't even have any graphical user interface.

Answer (score 2):

As I commented, many Linux systems (e.g. a rented VPS, a consumer router box, ...) don't have any graphical user interfaces (often above [X11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11)).

If you want a GUI toolkit in C for Linux, consider using [GTK](http://www.gtk.org/). Then look at [GtkFileChooserWidget](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkFileChooserWidget.html) & [GtkFileChooser](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkFileChooser.html)

If you want a GUI toolkit in C++ for Linux, consider using [Qt](http://qt-project.org/).

If you want a terminal interface, learn [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/).

If you want a web interface, use some HTTP server library like [libonion](http://www.coralbits.com/libonion/) or [Wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt), or make a FastCGI program for your existing web server.

Perhaps coding a simple shell script might be easier. Read [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/). You could also use a scripting language like Python, Ruby, Ocaml, ...

If you don't know about Linux programming, read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) first. See also [intro(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/intro.2.html) & [intro(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/intro.3.html)

Answer (score 1):

> ... a small program that needs to load a few files chosen by the user.

Just pass them as command-line arguments. It's much easier and doesn't tie you to a given GUI toolkit.

You can easily write a shell wrapper using kdialog on KDE, or dialog if you want curses in a terminal, or ... whatever other tool for whatever other environment.